# How to import data from one table to another table using Database: Seeding? (laravel 5.3)?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5.3

My DatabaseSeeder is like this :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $this->call('MasterLookupsTableSeeder')
    }
}
```

My MasterLookupsTableSeeder is like this :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MasterLookupsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('master_lookups')->insert([
            'id'            =>  '17',           
            'code'          =>  '002',
            'name'          =>  'sample data',
            'information'   =>  NULL,
            'created_at'    =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at'    =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I run `php artisan db:seed --class=MasterLookupsTableSeeder`, it will insert into to table master_lookups. It is still static. I want to create a dynamic where the data is inserted into master_lookups table taken from another table, for example akuns table. akuns table have field id, code, name, code_shopping.

I want like this :

code data from akuns table insert to field code in table master_lookups

name data from akuns table insert to field name in table master_lookups

code_shopping data from akuns table insert to field information in table master_lookups in the form of json. data type of field information is json.

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: Just grab all items from the table akuns and loop over doing an insert on the target table as the body of the closure? Akun::all()->each(function($akun)  { $masterLookup = new MasterLookup; $masterLookup->code = $akun->code; etc $masterLookup->save()}
Depending on the number of rows you have in your table you might want to use chunk instead of all to make sure you wont run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your akun table has a model Akun attached.
We assume the same thing for master_lookups (MasterLookup).

You can try something like:

```
Akun::all()->each(function($akun) { 
    $masterLookup = new MasterLookup; 
    $masterLookup->code = $akun->code;
    $masterLookup->name = $akun->name;
    $masterLookup->save()
}
```

Depending on the number of rows you have, you might want to use the `chunk` method instead of `all` to avoid running out of memory when trying to grab all the items.

Comment: it seems better to use foreach than each

Comment: Why? Taking advantage of the Laravel collections is better I think. I am pretty sure they are the same under the hood.